# Problems with email sent with Indy and ContentType = 'multipart/mixed'

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy

I use the code that follows to send an email from a Delphi application using Indy.

I just left the core part of my routine:

```
MailMessage.From.Name:= UserName;
MailMessage.Encoding := meDefault;
MailMessage.Subject := MessageObject;
with TIdText.Create(MailMessage.MessageParts, nil) do begin
  ContentType := 'multipart/alternative';
end;
with TIdText.Create(MailMessage.MessageParts, nil) do
begin
  Body.Text:= MessageText; // MessageText could be eithr HTML or TEXT
  ContentType := 'text/html';
end;
// recipients lists are populated
PrepareToList;
PrepareccList;
PrepareBccList;
// attachments are added to the MailMessage
AddAttachments;
MailMessage.ContentType :=  'multipart/mixed';
//usage of TIdSMTP to send mail
SMTP.Connect;
SMTP.Send(MailMessage);
```

The code above somehow works
with most SMTP servers, the message recieved in Outlook looks like this:

[image: mail as seen in outlook: normal case]

...but when i user a specific "problematic" SMTP server, I see:

[image: mail as seen in outlook: strange case]

The first case is ok, the second is odd.

The strange thing is that when using a specific SMTP server, I reproduce this problem, with all the others it is fine.

Could you please give me soem hint to further understand what goes on?

Comment: your screenshots are not helpful. What would be more helpful is if you showed the raw data of the emails instead. Have your read my articles on Indy's blog about how to create HTML emails properly? [HTML Messages](https://www.indyproject.org/2005/08/17/html-messages/) and [New HTML Message Builder class](https://www.indyproject.org/2008/01/16/new-html-message-builder-class/). One thing I notice is that you are not setting the `ParentPart` of the second `TIdText` object to refer to the first `TIdText`. You are creating a `multipart/alternative` part but you are not providing alternative text.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the reply. i will for sure read your articles. Please suggest how to read the raw data, you mean before sending it to the smtp server? thanks

Comment: `TIdMessage` has `SaveTo...()` methods. Most email readers have a way to view the raw data of an email. Compare what you send to what you receive. Your symptom sounds like maybe the "problematic" server is re-coding your email, for instance to add extra content, signatures, etc but is doing so incorrectly, causing corruption that breaks readers' ability to parse the parts correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks a lot. By reading your articles i noticed that my code comes from https://www.indyproject.org/2005/08/17/html-messages/ (some former colleague of my should have done copy and paste without oo much R&D) but `ParentPart := 0` is missing. I will add it and try if this solves the issue. i compared headers and raw data, the only significant difference is that the problematic mail is a plain text mail.

Comment: Are specifying ‘text/html’ as content type, when you create a plain text message? It should then be ‘text/plain’.